# Variable unexpectedly changes value (Pine script)

Tags: pine-script

Here is a simple script code:

```
//@version=4
study("test", overlay=false, precision=8)
var last_price = 0.0
var move = 0.0
if barstate.isrealtime
    move := move + abs(last_price - close)
last_price := close
plot(move)
```

As I understand, variable `move` all time must become bigger and bigger, but in reality not.
Why this situation may happened?

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behavior, and due to the [rollback process](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars). When your script gets to the last bar where `barstate.islast` becomes true, the value of `move` at the beginning of that bar is `0.0`, and this is the value that `move` is reset to before **every** iteration of your script in the realtime bar.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But exists any way how possible keep variables values from reset ?

Comment: No, you cannot save states in the realtime bar.

Comment: Maybe the closest you'll get from what you want is, for instance, to set your script to run at the end of every 1 minute candle. Not real time, but eventually a good approximation. I mean, I don't know your use case, of course, but think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I was almost giving up.

But since March, 2021, `varip` was introduced:

`varip - is similar to the var keyword, but variables declared with varip retain their values between the updates **of a real-time bar**.`

https://github.com/tradingview/pine_script_docs/blob/master/source/Release_notes.rst

And, more importantly: it works. :)